# how to encode the following representation of numbers

Tags: numbers, representation

well its a question i got in an assignment..and i am getting no clue to proceed
the question is like this
 A man want to communicate with alien to land him safely on earth station by providing
co-ordinates but alien use somewhat different representation of numbers(not decimal)
Alien representation contain the character set(o f a)
now for input (9,5) man gives him the following (foo,fa)
can you please give me hint or code so that i can try to write code myself

Comment: What do you know about bases other than 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- There are three symbols. In decimal (base-10), there are 10 digits: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9. In binary (base-2) there are two digits, 0 and 1. In base-16 there are 16 digits. Since there are three symbols in the alien system, could we make a guess about its organization?
- 5base10 = 12base3. 9base10 = 100base3. So (9,5) in decimal is the same as (100, 12) in trinary. Can we make a guess about which alien symbols represent which human digits?

Comment: THANKS i finally implemented it

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The alien is using a positional number system like we do. (In other words, it's probably not something like Roman numerals or spelling out the names of the numbers.)

Second hint: Consider how many characters are in the alien's number system.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they are ternary.

You want to convert decimal (base 10) to ternary (base 3).

You will notice instead of using `0`, `1` and `2`, the alien uses `o`, `f` and `a`. They basically map to the same numbers.

So to get the answer, convert from decimal to ternary, and then substitute the numbers for the alien characters.

#### Example PHP code

```
$chars = 'ofa';
$ternary = str_split(base_convert(9, 10, 3));
foreach($ternary as $num) {
   echo $chars[$num];
}
```

This is doable in any language, though PHP is fortunate enough to have a native `base_convert()` function.